# How to properly structure database calls in an express/mongoose application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

What is the correct way to access a mongodb database from Express ?

Right now, I am including my database handler `db.js` which contains `mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/db' );` every time I need to do a database call.

Should I use the same connection and passing my db object through callbacks or I can just include my db file every time ?

In other words, is `mongoose.connect` always re-using the same connection ?

**Edit**: my source code is public [here](https://github.com/pobourgeois/Notes), I am fairly new to nodejs/express applications and I am not sure if my application is structured properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to connect to your database once. In your other files, you need to include your models and use them to read / write to your database collections.

Edit: Looking at your code -- why don't you move your connect into your initialization script, and then include db.js to access your models?

Comment: I just moved my `connect()` to `instance.js`. It seems to work right now. So just including my models inside `db.js` should be enough after ?

Comment: Mongoose stores your state as connected once you successfully call connect. You need to include your models in each javascript file that references them because, otherwise, they are not defined. See what happens when you don't include db.js -- you will get an error "Note is not defined" (or something similar).

Please accept the answer...